# Traverse ecore model

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have generated model code from Ecore.
Within my model I have a derived reference: `derivedThings`.

What I want to do in the `derivedThingsImpl` is the following:

I want to traverse the whole model and depending on the element, I want to add it to a collection or not.

```
for(TreeIterator iter = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(rootObject); iter.hasNext();)
 ...
```

The problem is, how can I access the root object from the `derivedThingsImpl` ?! is there something like `getRootObject()` ?!

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
EObject e = this;
while(e.eContainer() != null) {
  e =  e.eContainer()
  if (e instanceof RootElement)
    break;
}
// No I should have the root element. Is this a good and clean way ?!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way of doing it:

```
EcoreUtil.getRootContainer(eObject);
```